# How to get first value of array php

Tags: php, wordpress

How can i get the first value of this array?

I want get jpeg value from each array, but it just returns "hh".

This is my code:

```
$image_output = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id );
var_dump($image_output);
foreach ($image_output as $value) {
    echo  $value;
}
```

This is my array

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(98) "localhost/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/11.jpeg"
  [1]=>
  int(170)
  [2]=>
  int(120)
  [3]=>
  bool(true)
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(63) "localhost/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/10.jpeg"
  [1]=>
  int(170)
  [2]=>
  int(120)
  [3]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

Where is my code wrong?

Comment: `echo  $value[0]`?

Comment: Why do you think that "hh" is returned? Your sample output proves you wrong

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correct it's a multidimensional array with the link in item 0 of each array.

```
Echo implode("<br>\n", array_column($image_output, 0));
```

This should output the links one on each line without looping